# Executing python script with a icon click

Tags: python, macos, click, icons, textwrangler

I am wondering how to run a python script (script.py) without going through terminal.  I'm using a mac with osx 10.9.5, I use TextWrangler, and run in terminal.  I was hoping there was a way to run the program by a single icon click.

Comment: I'm guessing that this will be quite OS dependent :-)

Comment: Haha thank you for pointing that out. I'm currently using osx 10.9.5